# Python Biult-in Methods

Tags: python, built-in-types

I am really confused about the replace python method.
i used the replace function in two instances but the output is really confusing.
This is the code below

```
story = 'there was once an old woman'

story2 = story.replace('an', 'a') .replace('old', 'young'))
print(story2)
```

and when i run the code below. the output becomes.
there was once a young woma
someone please tell me why was deleted from the woman.

Comment: replace() changes all instances of the text with the replacement.  So your `story.replace('an', 'a')` changes both the "an" word and the end of "wom**an**" to an "a"

Comment: Do not post images of code or links to such images.

Comment: Hi, your post has been downvoted, because you have done little research, and SO users are encouraged to downvote questions that do little research. This does not mean that your question is not acceptable on the platform; beginners questions indeed are! I echo @DYZ that you should write code out instead of posting an image. For future questions, try reading the documentation for an answer before asking it on SO: your question is answered here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace . But SO is still ok if you have problems with the docs, e.g. if the English is too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot reference:

The reason why `woman` turns into `woma` is because the 2 last letters of woman is 'an'. the .replace() function is set to replace all of the 'an's to 'a's. Since woman has 'an' as its last 2 letters, the 'an' is replaced with 'a' creating the illusion that the 'n' disappeared when actually 'an' was replaced with 'a'.

The second .replace("old", "young") function is placed on the 'a' string and since the word 'old' does not exist in this string. Nothing is changed in the output.

Basically, that screenshot has a lot of syntaxes that is highly likely to be unintended and wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much for the the answers, I clearly understand now..

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not match the image. The code is correct, but the code from the image is incorrect.

The second n was removed from woman because [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replaces all occurrences. To only replace `n` instances, pass a number.

```py
story = 'there was once an old woman'
story2 = story.replace('an', 'a', 1).replace('old', 'young')
print(story2)
# 'there was once a young woman'
```

You can chain the `.replace()` functions just fine.

Comment: this does the job, but it's a hard-code value you're passing in i.e `1` what if the user doesn't know what the no of occurrences of `"an"/"a"` solution should be somewhat dynamic :)

Comment: @FishingCode I'm not writing the code. That's for the end user. It's not up to us to refactor all of their code. There is a hard coded string `story` and everything in the `.replace()` is hard coded. So, it's appropriate per the guidelines.